# Sanitize AJAX jquery autocomplete script

Tags: mysql, ajax, security, codeigniter

I was seeking help in getting jquery autocomplete implemented and someone mentioned that that following code is susceptible to sql injections.  Being new to programming, I was unable to tell how/why.

Would someone be able to explain in more detail, and the specific steps to take to wall off the security risk?

Thanks

JS:

```
$( "#filter" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
        url: "http://rickymason.net/blurb/main/search/",
        data: { term: $("#filter").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data){
           var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                return obj.tag;
           }); 

           response(resp);
        }
    });
},
minLength: 2
});
```

Controller:

```
    public function search()
    {
        $term = $this->input->post('term', TRUE);
        $this->thread_model->autocomplete($term);
    }
```

Model:

```
    public function autocomplete($term)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tag
            FROM filter_thread ft
            INNER JOIN filter f
            ON ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
            WHERE f.tag LIKE '%".$term."%'
            GROUP BY tag");
        echo json_encode($query->result_array());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$term` unescaped in your query. A malicious user can submit a string like `' OR 1=1; DROP DATABASE;--` - and you certainly don't want that. Use mysql_real_escape_string() or the [MySQLi equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) to sanitize strings before putting them into a query.

Comment: I see. Is this generally only a problem when the user can type in information through an input field or something similar?  For instance, I have many forms that submit data as well, will these need to be sanitized (I believe they are actually, but just checking).

Comment: Any data that can modified by an attacker (cookies, user-agents, query string, POST data (including uploaded file names), headers, dynamic pathnames etc.) should not be used without being sanitized first.

Comment: remember, NEVER EVER trust the user.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to check user submitted data for unwanted characters before you use it in a query. That way you don't have people entering whatever they want in that field. When you use any user submitted data in a query unchecked, it could expose you to SQL injection attacks.

Here's a pretty decent explanation: http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/sql_injection.html

Answer (score 0):

Sql Injection is an important issue for web security. Please go through this site about sql injection then you will realize why you need to sanitize strings.

[SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)